# java.lang.NullPointerException: When saving jpa data using Gemfire cachewriter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-gemfire, geode

Jpa Repository save is working in all classes. But when trying to save in CacheWriter it is throwing NullPointerException(personRepository.save(entryEvent.getNewValue())). Any idea on this? Configured mysql database in application properties.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.javasampleapproach.gemfirerestapi.GemfireWriter.beforeCreate(GemfireWriter.java:28)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.cacheWriteBeforePut(LocalRegion.java:3131)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegionMap.invokeCacheWriter(AbstractRegionMap.java:3145)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegionMap.basicPut(AbstractRegionMap.java:2909)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.virtualPut(LocalRegion.java:5821)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegionDataView.putEntry(LocalRegionDataView.java:118)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPut(LocalRegion.java:5211)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.validatedPut(LocalRegion.java:1597)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.put(LocalRegion.java:1580)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegion.put(AbstractRegion.java:327)
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getPerson")
    public Iterable<Person> getPerson(@RequestParam("id") long personId,@RequestParam("age") int age, @RequestParam("name") String name) {
        try{
            Person bob = new Person();
            bob.setPersonId(personId);
            bob.setAge(age);
            bob.setName(name);
            Region<Long,Person> region=gemfireCache.getRegion("person");
            region.put(personId, bob);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Cachewriter:

```
public class GemfireCacheWriter implements CacheWriter<Long, Person>{
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

   @Override
    public void beforeCreate(EntryEvent<Long, Person> entryEvent) throws CacheWriterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        personRepository.save(entryEvent.getNewValue());
    }

    }
```

CacheWriter Config:

```
@Bean
    LocalRegionFactoryBean<Long, Person> personRegion(final GemFireCache cache) {
        LocalRegionFactoryBean<Long, Person> personRegion = new LocalRegionFactoryBean<>();
        personRegion.setCache(cache);
        personRegion.setName("person");
        personRegion.setPersistent(false);
        personRegion.setCacheWriter(new GemfireWriter());
        personRegion.setCacheLoader(new GemfireLoader());
        return personRegion;
    }
```

Comment: I will get back to the question later, but in the meantime you should have a look at this (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.1.x/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider-inline-caching) and specifically this (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.1.x/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider-inline-caching-using-spring-data-repositories).  No longer is it necessary to roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [`LocalRegion`](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/internal/cache/LocalRegion.java#L3129-L3152),  I don't think the `entryEvent` received by your `CacheWriter` could be `null`, so the actual `null` reference is probably `personRepository`. Have you correctly configured `spring-data-gemfire` to autowire the `PersonRepository`?, is the `CacheWriter` configured as a Spring bean (using the `@Component` as an example)?.

You can use the [Write Through Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-gemfire-examples/tree/master/basic/write-through) as a good starting point for implementing this use case.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Hey Juan, thanks for ur answer. Pls check Cachewriter Config(Added in top).  Cachewriter is all good. But problem is with personRepository only.

Comment: Your `CacheWriter` doesn't seem to be a Spring managed bean, so the framework will never be able to automatically set the `PersonRepository` through dependency injection... you either need to declare the `CacheWriter` as a spring managed bean (add `@Component` annotation and use component scanning), declare your `CacheWriter` as a `@Bean` within the java configuration as you're currently doing with the `LocalRegionFactoryBean`, or use constructor injection and directly pass an autowired instance of `PersonRepository` when creating the `CacheWriter` through the `personRegion` method.